# if user is blocked php include page, else include other?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help me, i am trying to incorporate this piece of code:

```
<?php
$blocked_users = blocked_users();
while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
include("includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php");
}
}
?>
```

to fit this piece of code as an else statement:

```
$profile_info_set = get_profile_info();
while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info_set)) 


        if (isset ($profile_id))
        if ($user['account_status'] == "Active")
        if ($user['account_type'] == "Escort") {
        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php");

        }
```

I have a table in my database that puts a users block status from 0 to 1. and if a user blocks someone and that user tries to access their profile then i am trying to make it so that the user goes to another page that says blocked. i am doing this through `<?php include(.. ?>`

At the moment i just tried putting this at the top of the page:

```
<?php
$blocked_users = blocked_users();
while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
include("includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php");



                }
}
?>
```

and whilst it is working and including the page mod_blocked.php its also bringing up mod_profile.php which is the default profile page and overlapping. So basically if a users not blocked they should go to mod_profile.php and if a users blocked they go to mod_blocked.php.

can someone please show me where im going wrong and how to achieve this?

Here's the entire page of code:

```
<?php
        $page_title = "Profile";
        include('includes/headerframe.php');


    // GET PROFILE ID FROM URL
    if (isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $profile_id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $blocked_users = blocked_users();
    while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
    if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
    include("includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php");



                    }
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    $user_info_set = get_user_info();
    if (!$user = mysql_fetch_array($user_info_set)) {
        include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php');

    }

        else if (!isset($profile_id)) {
                        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php");
                    }

    $profile_info_set = get_profile_info();
    while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info_set)) 


        if (isset ($profile_id))
        if ($user['account_status'] == "Active")
        if ($user['account_type'] == "Escort") {
                        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php");



                    }

                    else if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
                        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php");
                    }





                    $profile_info3_set = get_profile_info3();
    while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info3_set)) 

        if (isset ($profile_id))
        if ($user['account_status'] == "Active")
        if ($user['account_type'] == "Client") {
                        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_account.php");
                    } 



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple options here.

Add `break` or `die()` like such

```
<?php
$blocked_users = blocked_users();
while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
include("includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php");
break;
}
}
?>
```

Or, surround it in the `else`

```
<?php
$page_title = "Profile";
include ('includes/headerframe.php');

// GET PROFILE ID FROM URL
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $profile_id = $_GET['id'];
    die();
}

$blocked_users = blocked_users();
while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
    if ($block['blocked'] == '1') {
        include ("includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php");
    } else {
        $user_info_set = get_user_info();
        if (!$user = mysql_fetch_array($user_info_set)) {
            include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php');
        } else if (!isset($profile_id)) {
            include ("includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php");
        }

        $profile_info_set = get_profile_info();
        while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info_set))

            if (isset($profile_id))
                if ($user['account_status'] == "Active")
                    if ($user['account_type'] == "Escort") {
                        include ("includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php");
                    } else if ($block['blocked'] == '1') {
                        include ("includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php");
                    }

        $profile_info3_set = get_profile_info3();
        while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info3_set))

            if (isset($profile_id))
                if ($user['account_status'] == "Active")
                    if ($user['account_type'] == "Client") {
                        include ("includes/mod_profile/mod_account.php");
                    }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are up to, but when I got your question correct, you could do it the following way:

```
$page_title = "Profile";
include('includes/headerframe.php');

// stores the correct include file...
$toInclude = false;


// GET PROFILE ID FROM URL
if (isset ($_GET['id'])) {
    $profile_id = $_GET['id'];
}

// look up for blocked user..
$blocked_users = blocked_users();
while ($block = mysql_fetch_array($blocked_users)) {
    if ($block['blocked'] == '1')  {
        // don't do the include inside the loop
        // we simply set the $toInclude
        $toInclude = "includes/mod_profile/mod_blocked.php";
        break;
    }
}
$user_info_set = get_user_info();
// in case no include is set, and there is no profile...
if ( !$toInclude  && (!$user = mysql_fetch_array($user_info_set) || 
     !isset($profile_id)) ) {
    // we set the $toInclude now
    $toInclude = 'includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php';
}


if($toInclude) {
    // either blocked or no-profile
    include($toInclude);
} else {
    // user is not blocked, and you have a profile
    // proceed with your code for normal user handling here
}
```